# can power on ethernet for one poe swtich to another layer 2/3 switch?

Tags: networking, switch

My question is 
1. can we use 1 poe switch as power supply for another layer 2/3 switch?
2. If question 1's answer is yes then What should be maximum distance between those?
As per my reading in various websites, distance not more than 1000meter...
Can we use poe for 2km any how? means distance between 2 switches is 2km.

Comment: Copper Ethernet only goes 100m, not 1km. Fiber goes farther.

Answer (score 4):

Ethernet copper cable max distance is 100m. Over this distance you must switch (sic) to another technology. Cheap DSL converters or fiber optic, depending on the budget, existing wires...

And yes you can power one switch with POE from another... but check their respective power requirement and delivery.

Comment: Ethernet is a protocol and does not have a maximum distance. Most flavors of CAT 5 and 6 UTP have a maximum distance rating of 100m, but this absolutely does not apply to fiber that is carrying Ethernet traffic.

Comment: And it case it isn't clear, you can't do Power over Ethernet running over fiber.

Comment: @MikeyB absolutely. Copper must be the transport for PoE.

Comment: @MikeyB : sure that was obvious to me.

Comment: @bokan It was for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you'll need a switch like the [**HP 1810-8G**](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product.aspx?sku=10448238&pagemode=ca) in between.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the answer "no" if you need to put a switch in between?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to find switches are are powered over PoE, yes. Standard PoE and Ethernet limitations apply.

I know Cisco has some - if you're interested, contact your reseller or Cisco rep.